# How to generate resources for task?

Tags: sbt, sbt-assembly

For my `Runtime` configuration, I can define an extra `resourceGenerator` as follows:

```
resourceGenerators in Runtime <+= myResourceGeneratingTask
```

For the `assembly` task this does not work:

```
resourceGenerators in assembly <+= myResourceGeneratingTask
```

The error message is:

```
Reference to undefined setting:

  *:assembly::resourceGenerators from *:assembly::resourceGenerators (...\build.sbt:20)
```

When I change the 'append' operator `<+=` to the assignment `<<=`, it no longer causes any error, but my resource generator is not called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that I use sbt **0.13.5**. It works with Typesafe Activator 1.2.3, too (since it's based upon sbt 0.13.5).

`assembly` is a task not a configuration and doesn't offer `resourceGenerators` setting and hence the error - `undefined setting`.

You may however set the setting for a task in a given configuration, so the following is going to work fine:

```
resourceGenerators in (Runtime, assembly) += myResourceGeneratingTask.taskValue
```

Note that I use `+=` and `taskValue` combination which is preferred approach in 0.13. I also extracted a method `def makeSomeSources` to have it reusable in other use cases if necessary. See [Generating files](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Howto/generatefiles.html) in the official documentation of sbt:

> Because we want to add the task, and not the value after its
>   execution, we use `taskValue` instead of the usual value. It should be
>   scoped according to whether the generated files are main (`Compile`)
>   or test (`Test`) resources.

In your case, it's for `assembly` task in `Runtime` configuration.

**build.sbt** I used for reference:

```
import AssemblyKeys._

assemblySettings

def makeSomeSources(f: File): Seq[File] = {
  val content = "Hello"
  IO.write(f, content)
  Seq(f)
}

lazy val myResGenT = taskKey[Seq[File]]("My personal resgen")

myResGenT := {
  val log = streams.value.log
  val f = (resourceManaged in Compile).value / "resgen.xml"
  val fs: Seq[File] = makeSomeSources(f)
  log.info(s"Generating file(s): $fs")
  fs
}

resourceGenerators in Compile += myResGenT.taskValue

resourceGenerators in Runtime += myResGenT.taskValue

resourceGenerators in (Runtime, assembly) += myResGenT.taskValue
```

Executing `runtime:assembly` gives me the following output:

```
> runtime:assembly
[info] Generating file(s): List(C:\dev\sandbox\resourceGenerators\target\scala-2.10\resource_managed\main\resgen.xml)
[info] Including: scala-library.jar
[info] Checking every *.class/*.jar file's SHA-1.
[info] Merging files...
[warn] Merging 'META-INF\MANIFEST.MF' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Strategy 'discard' was applied to a file
[info] SHA-1: 875d4b95f38dc85d14e53bdcd10e442520aeeefd
[info] Packaging C:\dev\sandbox\resourceGenerators\target\scala-2.10\resourcegenerators-assembly-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
```

Comment: I had to replace the `+=`...`.taskValue` back to `<+=`, but then indeed your example works like a charm, thanks! This helped me find a solution for my actual project (which is more complicated due to the use of subprojects) - not sure that'd make a useful stackoverflow question though.

Comment: The reason for this is the version of sbt you use. Give the recent version 0.13.5 a shot and you won't look back. Thanks for accepting the answer.

Comment: Indeed upgrading from 0.13.0 to 0.13.5 made your example work, thanks again!